# UITableView - how to register a cell from secondary view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

If you drag a UITableViewCell onto the top toolbar of a view controller, it appears above the view controller in IB as a secondary view. This is nice because you can do all the layout there. But how do you then get a table view to load the cell from there?

This doesn't work:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyCustomTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
```

And since it's not in a separate nib file, `registerNib` doesn't seem appropriate either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although that may be possible you have several options when designing tableview cells. You can either design it in a separate .xib file or you can use a prototype cell. Below is an example of a separate .xib file. When you use a separate .xib you would use the registerNib method.

[image]

Or with a prototype cell in which the cell is automatically registered with the tableView.

[image]

Comment: I am aware of these options, but the question was about how to register a cell from secondary view.

Comment: Hmmm well @soleil i would suggest adding to your question as it isn't completely clear. Maybe even an image of what you are seeing would help.